# findWhere on backbone collection only returns one result

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, breeze

I have a backbone collection I am trying to add models to so I can show a list of available forms that you can add to the ui in a drop down. And this seemed to be working until they needed to be able to add more than one type.

It seems though that my findWhere statement when I'm trying to add to the collection is only returning the fist one that has the Show property instead of all of them(There are maybe twenty).

To add it I am doing something like this.

```
this.temp = new Backbone.Collection();
var api = breeze api stuff
this.temp.add(api.collections[(this.templateType)].findWhere({Show : true}))
```

Is there a way to modify the findWhere so it grabs them all instead of just the first one. I was searching, but I can't seem to find anything like this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There is no Breeze issue here that I can see. If you agree, would you please remove the `breeze` tag from your question? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation you will notice

> `findWherecollection.findWhere(attributes)`
>
> Just like where, but directly returns **only the first model** in the collection that matches the passed attributes.

Why don't you use `where` ?

> wherecollection.where(attributes)
>
> Return an **array of all the models** in a collection that match the passed attributes. Useful for  simple cases of filter

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where

Comment: Even with just the where it's only pulling back the first model

Comment: Are you sure that there are multiple models in your collection with that property? Try to debug it

Comment: There are over 200 models in the collection. I'm pulling from a massive database. I have been trying to debug this for the greater part of two days now...

Comment: @zazvorniki If you have 200 models in the collection, then it is probably advised that you paginate the results in the back end, and call the collection with query parameters such as offset and limit.